# Does storing a reference to LazyListState in ViewModel cause memory leak?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a LazyColumn and I want to scroll to the top of the list after swipe to refresh. I use Compose's pull refresh for swipe refresh layout. I am storing lazyliststate in my viewModel to scroll to top of the list after loadList call finishes.

```
`@Composable
fun pullRefreshList(
    contacts: List<String>,
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val viewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>()
    val refreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsState()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    viewModel.onRefreshFinished = {
        // Scroll to the top when the callback is invoked
        listState.scrollToItem(0)
    }

    val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, viewModel::loadList)

    Box(Modifier.pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)) {
        LazyColumn(state = listState, modifier = modifier) {
            items(contacts) { contactName ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(30.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clickable { navController.navigate("screen2") },
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                ) {
                    Text(text = contactName, fontSize = 24.sp)
                }
            }
        }

        PullRefreshIndicator(refreshing, pullRefreshState, Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
    }
}`


My View Model where I store reference to lazyliststate -

`class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _isRefreshing = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isRefreshing = _isRefreshing.asStateFlow()
    private var nextInt = 0
    var onRefreshFinished: (suspend () -> Unit)? = null

    fun loadList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _isRefreshing.value = true

            addToList()

            _isRefreshing.value = false
            onRefreshFinished?.invoke()
        }
    }
}`
```

So in xml based UI, usually we don't want to hold a reference to a view in a viewmodel because it can cause memory leaks? In compose, will this cause a leak?

Comment: Storing a reference to LazyListState in a ViewModel can cause a memory leak if not managed properly.

WeakReference: Instead of directly storing a reference to LazyListState, consider using a WeakReference to hold it. This way, if there are no other strong references to the LazyListState object, it can be garbage-collected.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? LeakCanary is indicating the same issue for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not